# How can I reset the history stack for many images at the same time in darktable?

Tags: darktable

How can I reset the history stack for many images at the same time in darktable?

I have edited many pictures. However I want to start from scratch. I understand how I can reset the history stack for a single image with "Compress history stack". However, for many hundred images it is very tedious. I need to reset the history stack for all images in question.

I am using darktable 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the straightforward way would be to reset the history stack of one of the photos; then in lighttable select that photo and "copy history stack"; then select all the photos you want to reset and "paste history stack" to them.

**This is a hack**: I didn't try this --- but probably removing all the `.xmp` files AND re-importing the images will do the trick.

Comment: I strongly recommend the second option because otherwise, you may lose more than just the history stack.

Comment: @bronger Now it is the first option... thanks, you're right of course.

Answer (score 18):

Actually there is a **discard history** feature inside darktable for exactly this. But as the [documentation](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/4.6/en/module-reference/utility-modules/lighttable/history-stack/) states:

> *"Beware: this action can not be undone!"*

In the **lighttable** view, select all images you want to reset, then in the right panel, find the module **history stack** and click **discard history**. That will "Physically delete the history stack of the selected images."

Further information in the [user manual](https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/4.6/en/module-reference/utility-modules/lighttable/history-stack/).

Comment: Thks for the information, but it seems it does not work on DT 2.0.5 german version.
Reset does not work on many pictures. Therefore I will try option 1.